# Convert char to array of chars

Tags: c++

I'm doing something like that:

```
char* test = "HELLO";
char* test2[6] = test; //
```

But it is not working, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Firstly: `const char* test = "HELLO";`.

Comment: `memcpy`/`strcpy` as C-arrays are not copy-able.

Comment: `char test2[6] = {test[0], test[1], test[2], test[3], test[4], test[5]}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't copy arrays in C++, at least not without a little help. In this case the function you need is `strcpy`

```
char* test = "HELLO";
char test2[6];
strcpy(test2, test);
```

Also note that an array of chars is `char[]` not `char*[]` (which is an array of char pointers).

Comment: Why convert it? It is already an array of chars.

Comment: It should be `const char* test`. Non-const is not valid, since it points to a literal.

Comment: True, but the question was about how to convert it.

Comment: You can't convert something that's not legal to have in the first place :-) It's undefined behavior.

Comment: Right. I was lost in thoughts about the conversion of char * test into an array of chars i.e test[i] and the assumption that it was a difference. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can only initialize an array with a string literal:

> 8.5.2 **Character arrays** [dcl.init.string]
>   1 An array of narrow character type (3.9.1), char16_t array, char32_t array, or wchar_t array can be initialized
>   by a narrow string literal, char16_t string literal, char32_t string literal, or wide string literal,
>   respectively, or by an appropriately-typed string literal enclosed in braces (2.13.5). Successive characters of
>   the value of the string literal initialize the elements of the array. [ Example:

```
char msg[] = "Syntax error on line %s\n";
```

I don't know the rationale for this but I'll take a guess and say that that it is meant to guarantee that direct initializations do not overflow the array (when the size is specified).